# jQuery plugin stops working when assigning an id to an element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an issue I was hoping someone could kindly help me with.  I'm currently building a webiste, and tried to use a jquery plugin for the first time to create a sticky navigation bar (http://stanhub.com/scroll-to-top-then-fixed-navigation-effect-with-jquery-and-css-free-download/).

When I assign an #ID to the nav tag, and change the CSS rule accordingly to apply just on this specific nav, the plugin stops working.  The problem is that I would like to have a few navs on my page and I don't see another option.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

And here is a link to the full code:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gbQBOo

**HTML:**

```
<section id="screen1">

    <p>Scroll down</p>

    <nav id="main-nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Team</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

</section>

<section id="screen2"></section>
<section id="screen3"></section>
```

**CSS:**

```
/* Navigation Settings */

#main-nav {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    background: #fff;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).bind('scroll', function() {
        var navHeight = $( window ).height() - 70;
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > navHeight) {
            $('#main-nav').addClass('fixed');
        }
        else {
            $('#main-nav').removeClass('fixed');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: No, building it from scratch.

Comment: The `<nav>` tag is not an absolute.  So you have formatting for a nav that will be applied to any other nav you add to the page.  You could use a div instead.

Comment: thanks, I've tried using a <div> but I'm afraid it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In CSS, `#main-nav` is more precise than `.fixed`, so it takes precedence.

You could:

1) change `.fixed` into `#main-nav.fixed`

2) set the `position` from `.fixed` to `fixed!important`

3) not use an id but a specific class for your nav, and make sure `.fixed` is defined after that new class